# SQL, триггер на обновление только одного столбца

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, sql-server, триггер

Триггер - **Нужно сделать так, что бы он обновлял только один столбец/ячейку** `update (select last_score from last_scores) values (@midarif)` -- это неудачная часть кода - я попытался так, но синтаксис не знаю. А через `insert into` - не то. Нужно как то через udpate или что-то в этом роде. Или же только `insert` можно там использовать?

```
Create trigger working
on record_book
after insert
as
begin
declare @learn int --ученик
declare @group int --группа
declare @less int -- предмет
declare @scor float --оценка
declare @midarif float = 0-- среднее арифметическое
select @learn = (select id_learner_rb from inserted) -- берем айди ученика
select @group = (select id_group_rb from inserted) -- берем айди группы
select @less = (select id_lesson_rb from inserted) -- айди предмета
select @scor = (select id_score_rb from inserted) -- оценку
select @midarif = (select @learn, @group,@less, (select (@scor+ sum(id_score_rb)/COUNT(id_learner_rb)) from record_book where id_learner_rb = @learn)
from record_book, learners, lesson, Groups where id_learner_rb = @learn) -- среднее ариф
update (select last_score from last_scores) values (@midarif) -- это неудачная часть кода
end
```

Comment: У `update` другой синтаксис: `update <table_name> set <column_name>=<value> where <condition>`.

Comment: По-моему, автор не въезжает. Триггер - это процедура, которая выполняется как реакция на изменение данных таблицы сторонним запросом.